# Is there a way to transform a full resolution and regular image to look like I took a photo of it with my cellphone from my computer screen?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm training a computer vision algorithm, and I want to give it some more robust data. For the application of the software I'm building, oftentimes people will take pictures of their computer screen with their phones and use those images, rather than the actual original image file to run the computer vision on.

Do you know what kind of transformations I can make to my already labeled image dataset to emulate what it would look like if someone used a cellphone to take a picture of a screen?

Like some qualities demonstrated below in the sample image of my screen for this question:
[image]

I guess this is what I'm thinking so far conceptually, but I'm not sure what libraries to use in Python:

1. The image resolution will probably drop, so modulating that to be lower or more commensurate with what a cellphone's granularity is
2. Adding in random color aberrations to the images, because when you take pictures of screens it seems like mini rainbows form?
3. Warping the angle the image is viewed at, since when someone takes a photo, they may not be taking it perfectly square/flat
4. Adding pixel-looking grids to the images to make them look more like the images taken of screens.

Is there anything I missed and do yall have any library recommendations or starting code to help me? I really want to avoid relabelling all of my data...

Thanks in advance!

I found this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/14001

It seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, but how do I translate this into code? Any library recommendations?

Comment: depending on the size of you dataset you might be better off just taking the pictures by hand and labeling again

Comment: you may also want to add some motion blur, because some people has shaky hands...